# Will "long i = 1;" cause an implicit type conversion in C?

Tags: c, implicit-typing

If I write "`long i = 1;`" instead of "`long i = 1l;`", will the `1` be recognized as `int` and then implicitly converted to `long`?

**Edit:** Thank you all. I see there's no type conversion. Is this also the case with the suffix `u` (like `10u`)? Then what's the use of those `l` and `u`?

Comment: could you explain why you are asking?

Comment: There's an HP compiler on an old version of HP-UX that will complain about converting 'int 1' into a 'long' if you tweak it hard enough, but it is very debatable whether it is worth making it whinge about it.  Most compilers won't complain - with justice.

Comment: To Mitch: Nothing special. I'm just wondering the usefulness of the suffixes.

Comment: There _is_ a type conversion, it's just that the compiler is free to optimize it away in generated code (which it usually does).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The compiler will see what you are trying to assign and set the value to 1 immediately.  There is no type conversion that happens with a literal.  Even if you said long x = 1.0, you won't see a runtime type conversion.

By the way, on Windows, long and int are the same so there wouldn't be a type conversion anyway.

[Edit: made last comment specific to Windows; removed reference to preprocessor]

Comment: 64-bit OS X and Linux aren't modern platforms, then? =)

Comment: Can you tell I'm a Windows programmer?  I didn't realize Linux and OSX changed the definition of long when they went to 64-bits.

Comment: Yep; I think that there are a few unixes that even adopted the ILP64 model, so you can't even assume that `int` didn't change with the transition to 64 bits.

Comment: The preprocessor is not involved in type conversion.

Comment: I've fixed what were called out as the errors but people keep voting this down.  If you are going to vote it down, please explain why so I can make the answer better.

Comment: Probably because your answer sounds misleading. There is a type conversion when you say `long x = 1.0`, but your answer makes it sound otherwise, for example.

Comment: Thanks GMan.  Is the word "runtime" really that confusing?

Comment: I'm not sure. Possibly, because the OP didn't ask about runtime specifically just conversions in general. There is a compile-time conversion though, which is what the OP was probably asking about.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the constant `1` is int, so technically a type conversion will be done but it'll be done at compile time and nothing is lost.

However, consider the more interesting example of:

```
int main(void)
{
    long long i = -2147483648;
    long long j = -2147483647 - 1;

    printf( " i is %lld, j is %lld\n", i, j);

    return(0);
}
```

I get the following results from various compilers:

- MSCV 9 (Version 15.00.21022.08):

  ```
              i is 2147483648, j is -2147483648
  ```
- GCC (3.4.5):

  ```
              i is -2147483648, j is 0
  ```
- Comeau (4.3.10.1):

  ```
              i is 2147483648, j is -2147483648
  ```
- Digital Mars:

  ```
              i is -2147483648, j is -2147483648
  ```

I'm not sure yet how to account for the differences. It could be one or more of:

- compiler bugs
- C90 vs. C99 rules in operand promotion ("`long long`" support is C99, but some of these compilers might be compiling for C90 with "`long long`" as an extension)
- implementation defined behavior
- undefined behavior

FWIW, the behavior of MSVC and Comeau is what I expected - which is something that many might still find surprising.  The logic (in my mind) for the first operation is:

- `-2147483648` gets tokenized as '`-`' and `2147483648`
- `2147483648` is an unsigned int (since it can't fit into an int - I believe this is different in C99)
- applying the unary '`-`' operator results in `2147483648` again due to unsigned arithmetic rules
- converting that into a long long doesn't change the sign.

The logic for the second operation is:

- `-2147483647` gets tokenized as '`-`' and `2147483647`
- `2147483647` is a signed int
- subtracting `1` results in `-2147483648` since there's no problem representing that number
- converting that into a long long doesn't change the sign.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern compilers should be smart enough to see that you're assigning the literal to a `long`, and will make the literal of that type instead of forcing a pre-assignment conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that if written exactly as stated, it will be equivalent to i = 1l;
Any conversion will be done at compile time.

However, if you write

long i = (unsigned int)-1;

then i will probably not be what you expected.

Comment: When I compile that, `i` is -1. How is this unexpected?

Comment: On a 64-bit system with a LP64 model and 2s-complement arithmetic (OS X or Linux, for example), this will assign the value 0x00000000ffffffffL to i.

Comment: That's not unexpected, that's just what happens when you convert between signed and unsigned types and make assumptions about type sizes for "normal" platforms.

Comment: I did say *probably*. If you do not know enough to already know the answer, I would suggest that 0x00000000ffffffff probably was unexpected.

Comment: As -1 can be represented by long, the conversion will not take place. Check the ansi c standard for the details of type conversion rules.

Answer (score 0):

Today's compilers will recognize it and generate the same result.